# Issue in deploying Grails 3.1.9 application in WebSphere 8.5.5.8

Tags: websphere-8, grails-3.1

I am trying to deploy an app developed in Grails 3.1.9 in WebSphere 8.5.5.8

I've generated .war file and installed successfully but, when I'm trying to access through link http://localhost/MyAPP/ following error appears:

Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: {0}

I am able to access the static resources in the app as below..

http://localhost/MyAPP/assets/apple-touch-icon.png

Pl. help at the earliest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Help!!! when I deployed the war, Websphere stop working. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WebSphere the application server port is 9080. So try accessing http://localhost:9080/MyAPP/ (you may not have deployed on web server)

Check `SystemOut.log` for specific issue. If it is related to data source then check the JDBC connection URL. If you are getting any `NoClassDefFoundError`, then add the corresponding jar in class path. In case of any resource loading issue, check the JDK version of your code and WebSphere.